# Deceptively attractive

Tags: adverbs

If I mention that someone is not good looking once you see them up close, does that make them “deceptively attractive” or “deceptively unattractive?”  My friend and I are having a discussion about language syntax and this came up.

Answer (score -1):

"deceptively attractive" means that "the attractiveness was deceptive".

But, "deceptively" is a deceptive word.

When referring to a person "deceive" or its derivations have a pejorative sense,   implying that the person had consciously, deliberately, *intended* to mislead.

So if *someone is not good looking once you see them up close*, the quality "good looking" may have been a perceptual error on the viewer's part, where the "someone" had made no attempt to deceive.

The perceptual error may have arisen because the "someone" had taken care to be well presented for the sake of feeling presentable - i.e. to look her best. But, isn't that what most rational people would do?

And then, there would be the "someone" who took excessive care to present a false, misleading image, a mimicry of attractiveness, with intention to deceive, but which failed under scrutiny.

Answer (score -2):

> Deceptively  attractive means  appears  to  be  attractive  but  not  attractive  in  reality.
>
> Deceptively  unattractive  means  appears to  be  unattractive  but  attractive  in  reality.

*Deceptively*  means  making  you  believe  something  which  is  not  true.

So   *somebody  is  deceptively attractive* may  be  the correct  choice  for  you.

Here  is  the  link  which  shows  the  meaning  of   deceptive.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/deceptive